# LDAP Authentication with Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap, http, httpd.conf, mod-auth-ldap

I am trying to setup LDAP authentication with apache.

Group Information:

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap-corporate -b "o=example.com,c=us" "cn=Security "

dn: cn=Security , ou=lm8100, o=example.com, c=US 
businessCategory: secadm 
cn: Security 
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames 
objectClass: epicGroup 
objectClass: top 
uniqueMember: cn=Kim Ldaf + uid=CLKM9876,ou=lm8100,o=example.com,c=US   
uniqueMember: cn=HLK MNOIL+uid=DKL06, ou=lm8100,o=example.com,c=us    
uniqueMember: cn=TREKS DNKO+uid=RIK02, ou=lm8100,o=example.com,c=US
```

This is my configuration and it is accepting all valid LDAP users but my requirement is need accept only valid users for that particular group:

```
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow 
Allow from all 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Protected" 
Require valid-user
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off 
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off 
AuthBasicProvider ldap 
AuthLDAPUrl ldap://HOST/o=example.com,c=us?uid?sub 
Require ldap-group cn=SC HelpDesk,o=example.com,c=US
```

Comment: Planning to use LDAP not Active Directory

Answer (score 1):

You have both

```
Require valid-user
Require ldap-group cn=SC HelpDesk,o=example.com,c=US
```

As per the [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#examples), you should have only

```
Require ldap-group cn=SC HelpDesk,o=example.com,c=US
```

Comment: If I am not keeping Require valid-user. None of the users are able to login.  In some examples I saw both, so I kept both.

Answer (score 0):

Use this directive to match the LDAP dn and then authenticate it.

Grant access if there is a Require ldap-dn directive, and the DN in the directive matches the DN fetched from the LDAP directory.